# Integrating product of linear functions over a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods

Given a triangle with vertices $N=\{A,B,C\}$, where the triangle is defined to be the convex hull of those vertices, the nodal basis function is defined to be $$\phi_P(x) = \begin{cases} 1, x = P \\ 0, x \in N \setminus \{P\} \end{cases}$$

where $P \in \{A,B,C\}$

Followed by linear interpolation between these values, so that $\phi_P \in \mathcal{P}_1$.

So the nodal basis functions look like this:[image]

So they are just linear functions over the triangle. I now have to calculate $$\int_T \phi_i \phi_j dx, i \neq j, i,j\in \{1,2,3\}$$.

With $\phi_i = a_ix + b_iy + c, (x,y)\in T$

Can someone please tell me how to integrate such a term?

Comment: Apply a linear transform to map the triangle $T$ to a triangle $\Delta$ with vertices at $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$. Let's say $A \mapsto (0,0)$, $B \mapsto (1,0), C \mapsto (0,1)$. Since the Jacobian is a constant, one has
$$\frac{\int_T \phi_B \phi_C dxdy}{\int_T dxdy} = \frac{\int_{\Delta} xy dxdy}{\int_\Delta dx dy} = \cdots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the triangle $T_*$ with vertices $A_0=(0,0)$, $A_1=(1,0)$, $A_2=(0,1)$ one has $\phi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\phi_2(x,y)=y$. This implies
$$\int_{T_*}\phi_1(x,y)\phi_2(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} x y\>dy\>dx=\ldots={1\over24}\ .$$
From "general principles" (see achille hui's comment) it then follows that for an arbitrary triangle $T$ you have
$$\int_T\phi_i\phi_j\>{\rm d}(x,y)={1\over12}{\rm area}(T)\qquad(i\ne j)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have one more question why do we integrate the function $xy$ over the triangle $T_*$? You calculate the elements of the so called local mass matrix this way, so the i,j-th element is the integral $\int_T \phi_i \phi_j d(x,y)$, it doesn't seem right to me that all the elements would have the same value.

Comment: What if $i=j$ ?

Comment: @badmf Maybe a late response, but if $i=j$, then we get $\frac{1}{6} \text{area}(T)$