# Integral of a product of hat basis functions raised to arbitrary powers over a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Given a triangle $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $A,B,C$ let $\phi_A, \phi_B, \phi_C: K \to \mathbb{R}$ be hat basis functions. They are affine functions defined at nodes such that, for example: $\phi_A(A)=1$ and $\phi_A(B)=\phi_A(C)=0$, followed by linear interpolation.

In other words, they each form a "hat" above the triangle.
Here's a link to [a visualisation of hat basis functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64G65.png). It comes from [a related article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322328/integrating-product-of-linear-functions-over-a-triangle), asking about a special case of this question.

The problem is to prove:
$$\int_K\phi_A^m\phi_B^n\phi_C^pdxdy=\frac{2m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+2)!}|K|$$

It is an equation 3.64 from the book [The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation, and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-33287-6)
. It is provided without proof, with only a claim that it should be easy to prove using induction.

Comment: Here's a free link that opens to the page with the equation: https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~leykekhman/courses/MATH_5520/fa_2017/Mats%20Larson,%20Bengzon,%20Theory,%20Imlementation%20and%20Applications.pdf#page=81

Comment: Take a look at [Triangle Integrals](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/momenten/integral.htm). An integral alike to the one you asked for is in there, together with an elaborate derivation.